# C++ Functional procedure in elements of programming

Tags: c++, stl, std-function, c++-concepts

I am reading the [Elements of Programming](http://elementsofprogramming.com/) by Stepanov & Jones, implementing things as I go using concepts from c++20. Early on, the authors define *functional procedures*:

> A functional procedure is a regular procedure defined on regular types, with one or more direct inputs and a single output that is returned as the result of the procedure

In their code samples, they use it like so:

```
 template<typename T>
     requires(FunctionalProcedure(T))
 struct codomain_type;
```

But nowhere is `FunctionalProcedure` defined (I could not find it anyway). The thing I find interesting is that in their implementation, they use a simple template parameter (`T` in the code above) to capture the procedure. Is such a thing possible using regular c++?

For example, in my code, I am using

```
template <typename Op, typename... Args>
concept FunctionalProcedure = std::regular_invocable<Op, Args...>;
```

But then, I keep carrying the parameter pack `Args` in every single concept / metafunction I create. Most type traits / concepts from the standard require both the callable and its arguments, but I don't think it's possible to get that info from the lambda type (or functor for that matter). I can only do that easily if I stick with `std::function`.

Is there a way around this issue? Are they able to do this in the book because they use a modified, simpler version of c++?

Comment: Using a single template type `T` for a callable "object" (function, lambda, or anything else that is callable) is common practice in the standard library itself. And your requirement seems to be similar to [`std::is_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function).

Comment: Yes, i used it myself many times for predicates and the like. However, in this specific case, i need more than just calling the function. I also need to query its argument/return types, etc.